# What is wrong with my CSS code?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML / CSS. I want to build a web site but I stumbled across a problem.

My divs inside my "content div" have a blank space at the top from the line div, and I can't seem to figure out what is causing the problem. Can someone please help? I will much apreciate it.

Thank you!

```css
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Vlad Olar</title>

    <style type="text/css">
  
  body {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   font-family:Lato, Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
   background-color:#D8DCE1;
  }
  
  .clear {
   clear:both; 
  }
  
  .fixedwidth {
   width:960px;
   margin:0 auto;
   padding:0 0;
  }
  
  #topbar {
   background-color:#4C7585;
   height: 40px;
   width: 100%;
  }
  
  #front {
   height: 360px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color:#D8DCE1; 
  }
  
  #line {
   height:10px;
   width:100%;
   background-color:#4C4C4C;
  }
  
  #foto {
   height:120px;
   width:120px;
   background-color:#4C4C4C;
   border-radius:60px;
   z-index:3;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   top:-55px;
   margin-left:103px;
  }
  
  #gaming {
   height:120px;
   width:120px;
   background-color:#4C4C4C;
   border-radius:60px;
   z-index:3;
   float:right;
   position:relative;
   top:-55px;
   margin-right:103px;
  }
  
  #design {
   height:120px;
   width:120px;
   background-color:#4C4C4C;
   border-radius:60px;
   z-index:3;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   top:-55px;
   margin-left:198px;
  }
  
  #content {
   margin:0;
   padding:0; 
  }
  
  #fotocontent {
   background-color:#A48251;
   height:500px;
   width:320px;
   float:left;
  }
  
  #designcontent {
   background-color:#D1A366;
   height:500px;
   width:320px;
   float:left;
  }
  
  #gamingcontent {
   background-color:#A48251;
   height:500px;
   width:320px;
   float:left;
  }
 
  #footer {
   background-color:#4C7585;
   height: 40px;
   width: 100%;
  }
  
  #container {
   margin:0;
   padding:0; 
  }

 </style>

</head>
```

```html
<body>

 <div id="container">
    
     <div id="topbar">
         
            <div class="fixedwidth">
            
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="front">
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="line">
        
         <div class="fixedwidth">
             
                <div id="foto">
                
                </div>
                
                <div id="design">
                
                </div>
                
                <div id="gaming">
                
                </div>
                
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="clear">
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="content">
         
            <div class="fixedwidth">
             
                <div id="fotocontent">
               
                </div>
                
                <div id="designcontent">
               
                </div>
                
                <div id="gamingcontent">
               
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="clear">
        
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer">
         
            <div class="fixedwidth">
            
            </div>
            
        </div>
    
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I am not getting any blank space in the browser

Comment: It's because of `position: relative;` and `top: -55px;` on `#foto`, `#gaming` and `#design`. You could try adding `position: relative;` to `#line`  and set `#foto`, `#gaming` and `#design` relative to it by setting them as `position: absolute;` and adjusting `top` and `left` values accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HiddenHobbes wrote you have the problem because of *#foto*, *#design* and *#gaming* are pulling down *.clear* div (remove *top: -55px;* and you will see it).

If you do not want to recalculate margins you can wrap those block in some wrapper with *position: absolute;* to prevent pulling down behaviour on next div.

In your html

```
<div id="line">
    <div class="fixedwidth">
        <div class="foowrapper">            
            <div id="foto"></div>            
            <div id="design"></div>            
            <div id="gaming"></div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your css

```
.foowrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.fixedwidth {
    position: relative;
}
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mandarin6b0/9kc9og46/)

Answer (score 0):

I know your new to html and css but you realy need to make your css in a different file, to do this use `<link rel="stylecheet" href="style.css">`

Also you should start every html file with this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    (content)

</body>
</html>
```

But to anwser your question:
"My divs inside my "content div" have a blank space at the top from the line div"

This can easly be solved by given the div a margin-top:-(x)px;